# Python dictionary to Pandas data frame with lists as values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to convert the following dictionary:

```
links = { "a": ["aa", "ab", "ac"], "b": ["ba", "bb", "bc", "bd"] }
```

to a Pandas data frame like:

```
col_a   col_b
  a       aa
  a       ab
  a       ac
  b       ba
  b       bb
  b       bc
  b       bd
```

which is a little bit different than the classic dictionary to Pandas examples. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In pandas 0.25.0

```
pd.Series(links).explode().reset_index()
```

Comment: This is great but does not work for list of dictionaries with multiple dictionaries within it

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension to create a list of `(col_a, col_b)` tuples, then use `DataFrame.from_records()`:

```py
records = [(k, i) for k, v in links.items() for i in v]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=["col_a", "col_b"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this with list comprehension and native python operators:

```py
d = [([k]*len(v), v) for k,v in links.items()]
d2 = list(map(lambda x:sum(x, []), zip(*d)))
df = pd.DataFrame(d2).T
df.columns = ['col_a', 'col_b']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a df using from_dict then transpose it and re-arrange and rename:

```
(
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(links, orient='index')
    .T.stack()
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    .sort_index()
    .reset_index()
    .set_axis(['col_a','col_b'], 1, inplace=False)
)

col_a   col_b
0   a   aa
1   a   ab
2   a   ac
3   b   ba
4   b   bb
5   b   bc
6   b   bd
```